Isa 56 & Matt 16:13-28's Sudden Shocking About-turn from graciousness to being rudely harsh Vs Exo 34:6, Ps 145:8, Ps 103:8 's "Slow to anger"

Isaiah 56
New American Standard Bible 1995
56 Thus says the Lord, “Preserve justice and do righteousness, For My
salvation is about to come And My righteousness to be revealed. 2 “How
blessed is the man who does this, And the son of man who takes hold of
it; Who keeps from profaning the sabbath, And keeps his hand from
doing any evil.” ………more scripture …………………. ….more scripture…more
scripture……..
**4 For thus says the Lord, “To the eunuchs who keep My
sabbaths ………more scripture …………………. 5 To them I will give in My house and within My walls a memorial,……more scripture …
6 “Also the foreigners who join themselves
to the Lord, To minister to Him, and to love the name of the Lord………more scripture ………………….
7 Even those I will bring to My holy mountain
And make them joyful in My house of prayer.**
………more scripture ………………….
9 All you beasts of
the field, All you beasts in the forest, Come to eat. 10 His watchmen
are blind, All of them know nothing. All of them are mute dogs unable
to bark, ………more scripture …………………. Each one to his unjust gain, to
the last one. 12 “Come,” they say, “let [g]us get wine, and let us
drink heavily of strong drink; And tomorrow will be like today, only
more so.”


Matthew 16:13-28
New American Standard Bible 1995
Peter’s Confession of Christ
13 Now when Jesus came into the district of Caesarea
Philippi, He was asking His disciples, “Who do people say that the Son
of Man is?” 14 And they said, “Some say John the Baptist; and others,
[a]Elijah; but still others, [b]Jeremiah, or one of the prophets.” 15
He said to them, “But who do you say that I am?” 16 Simon Peter
answered, “You are [c]the Christ, the Son of the living God.” 17 And
Jesus said to him, “Blessed are you, Simon [d]Barjona, because flesh
and blood did not reveal this to you, but My Father who is in heaven.
…more scripture…….
Jesus Foretells His Death
21 From that time [k]Jesus began to show His
disciples that He must go to Jerusalem, and suffer many things from
the elders and chief priests and scribes, and be killed, and be raised
up on the third day. 22 Peter took Him aside and began to rebuke Him,
saying, “[l]God forbid it, Lord! This shall never [m]happen to You.”
23 But He turned and said to Peter, “Get behind Me, Satan! You are a
stumbling block to Me; for you are not setting your mind on [n]God’s
interests, but man’s.”

Isaiah 56 begins gracious, compassionate, and encouraging tone directed towards foreigners and eunuchs regarding what their roles will be in the Holy Ancient Israelite nation.
However, Isaiah 56:9 takes on a Shocking, Sudden about-turn/about-face by becoming rudely harsh which seems to be fire and brimstone preaching.
Matthew 16:13-28 is another example of how biblical scripture suddenly makes an about-turn by turning from graciousness and compassion  to being rudely harsh.
To elaborate, in Matthew 16:13-28 , Jesus Christ credits the Apostle Peter for recognizing & claiming  though The Heavenly Father that Jesus Christ is “The Christ, The Son of the Living God.”
When Jesus Christ states that He will be tormented and ultimately killed by the established Jewish religious order, Peter passionately & emphatically disagrees with Jesus Christ in regard to the suffering and death that Jesus Christ will undergo.
Jesus Christ angrily yells at Peter by calling Him Satan by saying that Peter had man’s interest in his heart as opposed to God’s interest.
My problem with both Matthew 16:13-28 and Isaiah 56 is the nature of their narrative/plot/subplot.  In other words, said shocking, sudden about-turn nature seem to contradict the following verses:

Exodus 34:6
New American Standard Bible 1995
6 Then the Lord passed by
in front of him and proclaimed, “The Lord, the Lord God, compassionate
and gracious, slow to anger, and abounding in lovingkindness and
truth;


Psalm 145:8
New American Standard Bible
8 The Lord is gracious and
compassionate; Slow to anger and great in mercy.


Psalm 103:8
New American Standard Bible 1995
8 The Lord is compassionate and gracious, Slow to anger and abounding in
lovingkindness.

Exodux 34:6, Psalm 145:8 and Psalm 103:8 seem to suggest that God Only gradually becomes righteously angry which is Not what occurs in Matthew 16:13-28 and Isaiah 56.
How can one reconcile the different natures when comparing Exodus 34:6, Psalm 145:8 and Psalm 103:8 to Matthew 16:13-28 and Isaiah 56?

'Rudely harsh' is your opinion. This whole question is a matter of opinion, not of balanced judgment and unbiased righteousness.

The sudden change of tone in Jesus' statements to Peter are neither rude nor hard to understand. Peter had just been given divine revelation from the Father regarding exactly who Jesus Christ is, and made a confession of faith in Jesus. This wasn't his own idea. Jesus clearly said the Father had revealed this massive truth to Peter. This truth needs to be revealed to every person who is to grasp that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of the living God. Without understanding and confessing that monumental truth, nobody can be saved.
Shortly after that, Peter then heard Jesus speak of his impending death, and began to rebuke Jesus. What? He began to rebuke the one who he had just confessed as being the Son of the living God? Peter was an impetuous sort of man, yes, but this was disgraceful! Had he instantly forgotten what Jesus had told him about the Father's revelation? Apparently. Instead of building on the divine revelation of the Father, he blurted out his own ideas. Therefore Jesus did not tolerate Peter's rebuke for one second. Peter's words might just as well come from the devil - it was as if the devil was whispering through Peter, trying to put Jesus off from the sacrificial death that was the reason why he came as man - to die. Therefore Jedus rebuked Peter in the strongest possible terms, and rightly so.
As for the Isaiah passages... Two categories of people are being addressed. At the start of the chapter, the Lord is encouraging those who would observe his ways and refrain from evil. But from verse 9 the tone changes because a different category of person is being addressed. Those in Israel who should have been alert watchmen looking out for the interests of the nation and God's holy name have failed in their duty. They have proven themselves to be greedy, selfish wine-bibbers. There was no chapter break in Isaiah's scroll. The anger of the Lord continues to be expressed from the start of chapter 57. Read through the whole of chapter 57 and see how wicked men are exposed by the Lord as such, while the conclusion is that God dwells with humble and contrite people, granting peace and healing to them. But for the wicked, there is no peace.
Why should anyone be surprised at the Lord's gentle, loving encouragements for those seeking to honour him, and the Lord's sternest rebukes for those who continue to dishonour him?
God always allows enough time for sinners to repent and stop doing evil. But he knows when they are set in their ways, and so hardened in heart, that there is no healing for them. God's wrath will come, eventually. But fools think that because he is long-suffering and patient, they will be able to carry on in their wicked ways and nothing will happen. For such ones, the Bible contains the strongest possible exposure.
"Do not be deceived. God is not mocked. For whatsoever a man soweth, that he shall also reap." Galatians 6:7.  And none of them will be able to say God neither warned them, nor gave them enough time to repent. The Bible is full of such warnings, plus real-life examples of the two outcomes for those two types of people.

Regarding the sudden change in tone in Isaiah 56, vs. 9 represents a new section of the poem, or possibly a different poem altogether, which was not originally joined to the first. The following is from a footnote in the NABRE:

56:1–8 This poem inaugurates the final section of the Book of Isaiah... In this
opening poem, the references to “keeping the sabbath” (vv. 2, 4, 6),
“holding fast to the covenant” (vv. 4, 6) and “God’s holy mountain” as
a house of prayer (v. 7), all tell of the postexilic community that
was establishing itself again in the land according to the pattern of
God’s word given through the prophet.

Isaiah 56:9 represents a switch in focus, predicting what will happen if God's people do not follow the guidelines mentioned in 56:1-8; or it could be a new writing inserted when the Book of Isaiah reached its final form. The NABRE views 56:9–57:21 as a separate section of the Book, but emphasizes that, like the opening section, it offers hope as well as judgment:

This section is made up of two pronouncements of judgment
(56:9–57:2; 57:3–13) and an oracle of salvation (57:14–21), each of
which ends with a reversal of imagery and language. While there are
harsh indictments against the corrupt leaders of Israel (56:9–12), a
promise of peace is offered to those who are just (57:1–2).

With regard to Matthew 16, the reason for the abrupt change in Jesus' emotion is that Peter, immediately after being declared the head of the Church, has opposed Jesus' destiny to go to the Cross. Peter's opposition is understandable since in Matthew's narrative (unlike John's where the Jesus' sacrifice is the plan from the beginning), the idea of Jesus' impending death takes Peter by surprise. However, Jesus has just declared that Peter is a rock and will be the head of his Church (vs. 18). To show public disagreement with Jesus was bad enough, but to stand in opposition to "Christ crucified" could not be tolerated. Thus, Matthew and Mark both present Jesus as harshly scolding Peter for this.
Conclusion: Sudden changes in the divine attitude as expressed in the Bible are due to a variety of causes. In Isaiah 56, the change marks a shift from section to another, possibly representing two distinct writings that were not originally joined. In Matthew 16, the shift is used by the author to emphasize the seriousness of denying that the Cross was essential to God's plan of salvation.
